# Change selected option when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

When the user changes the selected value in the select box, it will refresh the page, add the selected text value to the existing URL and reset the select box default to the value selected by the user before page refresh.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

HTML code:

```
<select class="selectedForm">
    <option value="one" selected>one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    <option value="four">four</option>
</select>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(".selectedForm").change(function() {    
   $('.selectedForm option:contains(' + this.value + ')').prop({selected: true});    
   alert( $('.selectedForm').find(":selected").val() );
   if ( window.location.href.indexOf("&") > -1 )  {
       window.location.search = '?toWhere=Cursos&q='+$('.selectedForm').find(":selected").text();
   } else {
       window.location.search += '&q='+$('.selectedForm').find(":selected").text();
   }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/awfx6rLg/)

Comment: Are you saying that after refresh the value in select control is not selected by default?

Comment: @cackharot nop. wht i am saying is that the selected default, needs to change to the selected clicked by the user

Comment: @KooiInc are you saying to remove: "selected" from the first element?

Comment: I think what he wants to say is that he wants the user to select something from the selectbox, then reload the page for whatever reason I don't yet grasp and after the reload, the selectbox should still have the previously selected value? And all this without server side code / plain javascript.

Comment: You need to set the value on `ready`. Since you're setting it in url, you can read from there.

Comment: See the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/awfx6rLg/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the value of the selector after a reload you could use something like:

```
$(".selectedForm").on('change', function() {
  var _loc = String(location.href)
      ,loc  = _loc.substr(0, _loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
      self.location.href = loc + '?selected='+this.value;
});

// handler to load the selected option on page load
function loadSelectedOpt() {
    var loc = location.search;
    if (loc.length) {
        $(".selectedForm").val(loc.split('=')[1]);
    }
}
```

In words: add the selected option value to the querystring of the current location (`?selected=[selected value]`), reload the page, and use the querystring to set the value of the selector when the page is reloaded.

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/q6y9xLb9/) demo

Answer (score 3):

From [get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html),

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

$(function(){
   var q= getUrlVars()["q"];
   if(q){
       $('.selectedForm option:contains('+q+')').prop('selected',true);
   }    
});
```

And if you are using `server side script` like `PHP` then, it is more easy to get by using `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

Also you can change your drop down onchange event like,

```
$(".selectedForm").change(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("&") > -1) {
        window.location.search = '?toWhere=Cursos&q=' + $('.selectedForm option:selected').text();
    } else {
        window.location.search += '&q=' + $('.selectedForm option:selected').text();
    }
});
```

Something [like that](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/awfx6rLg/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by storing the value in localstorage and on page loads you have to set the value again to the dropdown. This is the only way in front end.

Otherwise you can do this by sending the value to backend and getting back on page loads.

Hope this will solve your problem!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is after a page refresh, all resources are reloaded. Since the dropdown and your javascript is reloaded, this.value will not have a valid value that you are looking for to set the dropwdown.

You can either use local storage or simply retrieve the previously selected value from your query string. Further, you will need to set it during `load` event of the page. 
Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var queryStringBegin = window.location.search.indexOf("&q=");

    if ( queryStringBegin > -1 )  {
        var queryStrValue = window.location.search.substr(window.location.search.indexOf('&q=')+3);
        $('.selectedForm option:contains('+queryStrValue+')').prop({selected: true});
    }
});
```

NOTE: Further checks may be required in case `'&q='` is not always the last section of the query string.